# Determine an Odd/even Number, And Use While Loop To Add From Counter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, sum

I do not know why it stops looping after satisfying the condition sometime(eg.getting the sum of number from where it precedes). I believe that there's something wrong with the code. Where is it?

```
var init = parseInt(prompt('enter an odd or even no.'));
var sec = init%2;

if (sec != 0) {
    var loop = 5;   
    while (loop < 10) {
        var num = 1;
        loop += loop; 
        num += 2
    }
    document.write(num);
} else {
    document.write('None');
}
```

Comment: `parseInt(1)`??

Comment: what do you expect, what the code should do?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the loop and the algorithm in the loop?

Comment: The only outcomes of these code can be `None` or `3`

Comment: @ScottMarcus How did you manage that? I run it in the console and I got 3.

Comment: @ScottMarcus it cannot ever be 11.

Comment: @ScottMarcus if your result is 11 for w/e reason, you'd better open an issue with your CPU manufacturer asap...

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do? Variables declared with `var` don't have block scope, so it can be clearer to declare them all at the top of your code.

```js
var init = parseInt(prompt('enter an odd or even no.'));
var sec = init % 2;
var loop = 5;
var num = 1;
  
if(sec != 0) {
  while(loop < 10) {
    num+=2; 
    loop++;   
    document.write(num);
  }
}  else { 
  document.write('None');
}
```

Comment: Yeah. you're right, this is just the problem I am encountering. But, how do I get the sum of the numbers every time it iterates? say the sum that I should get is supposed to be 35.

Comment: @JpMC if you run Scott's code it should do what you expect now, since Scott removed the num = parseInt(1). Instead, he now accumulates 2 upon every interaction (which we believe is what you wanted to express)

Comment: Yeah. Logically. However, it only prints number "357911 "

Comment: That's because you're printing everything in the same line. But it is accumulating. Look carefully: 3 - 5 - 7 - 9 - 11

Comment: yeah I got the idea now. 
loop 5<10 output 1+2   
6<10 output 3+2
7<10 output 5+2
8<10 output 7+2
9<10 ouput 9+2
Therefore the number it accumulates resulted to 11

I did put it outside the brace where the while loop sets up the statements.

Answer (score 0):

The looping is happening, but you're just not seeing it because you don't print anything when it loops.

Your code should be like this instead:

```
var init = parseInt(prompt('enter an odd or even no.'));
var sec = init%2;

if (sec != 0) {
    var loop = 5;   
    while (loop < 10) {
        var num = 1;
        loop += loop; 
        num += 2
        document.write(num);
    }

} else {
    document.write('None');
}
```

See that `document.write(num)` now is INSIDE your loop, so it will print every time it loops through.

Previously, it was set outside, so essentially what was happening is that you were only seeing the result AFTER the last iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `num` with `1` outside of the `while` statement, because you assign this value for every loop.

The I suggest to declare all variable in advane at top of the code. You may assign here known values, too.

```js
var init = parseInt(prompt('enter an odd or even no.'), 10),
    sec = init % 2,
    loop = 5,
    num = 1;

if (sec != 0) {
    while (loop < 10) {
        loop += loop;
        num += 2;
    }
    document.write(num);
} else {
    document.write('None');
}
```

Comment: That is not the problem. Please see my answer.

Comment: @ThalesMinussi That is ***a*** problem.

Comment: It depends. The OP thinks it's not looping. But it IS. Whether his looping logic is broken or not that's another story.

Comment: @ThalesMinussi Your answer is an assumption, Nina's is an actual semantic fix. Whether it is or not what OP wanted to achieve is a separate question.

Comment: "I do not know why it stops looping after satisfying the condition". To me it doesn't sound like an assumption. To me, the OP clearly states it stops looping but does not no why.